# How to show audio keyframes in Adobe Premiere CC?

Tags: premiere

How to show audio keyframes in Adobe Premiere CC?

`Show Audio Keyframes` option is `ON` although I can't see any keyframes on the timeline.

I am sure, keyframes are there, since volume controls change in `Audio Clip Mixer` as I move play head.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to expand the track to be large enough to see the waveforms and overlaid keyframes.  Mouse over the horizontal line that divides A2 from A3, drag downward, and your waveforms and keyframes should be revealed.

If you right-click in the waveform area, you have the option as to which keyframes it will display in the window.  By default it's Volume:Level, but it could be Panner:Balance (or others).

Comment: Oh man, I just spent an hour Googling, and all of the results on various forums were nonsense because they neglected to first say "expand the track to be large enough to see...".  Thank you!

Comment: I also found this to be helpful: To edit audio keyframes to create a fade, click the Pen icon in the toolbar. Create two keyframes, and then drag them. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAoZSCXSfHs